# Trying to take user input to populate a stack with strings using getline(), but it makes my stack's first element is a space

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void display_stack(stack<string> st) 
{
    while(!st.empty()) 
    {
        cout << st.top() << ", ";
        st.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack<string>Cars;
    int n;
    string name;

    std::cout<<"How many elements do you want in your stack?"<<endl;
    std::cin>>n;
    std::cout<<"Enter types of cars: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        getline(cin,name);
        Cars.push(name);
    }

    std::cout<<"Initial Stack: ";
    display_stack(Cars);

    int size = Cars.size();
    string top = Cars.top();
    cout<<"\nThe size of the stack is: "<<size<<endl;
    cout<<"The top of the stack is: "<<top<<endl;
}
```

How many elements do you want in your stack?

3

Enter types of cars: kia
ford

Initial Stack: ford, kia, ,

The size of the stack is: 3

The top of the stack is: ford

Trying to take user input to populate a stack with strings using getline(), but it makes my stack's first element is a space.

So the problem is that for some reason it is taking a space as the first element of the stack, and only allows me to manually input two of the three items.